# Water dissociation constant $K_w$ in vapour, or are there charges entities ($\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{HO-}$,...) in water vapour?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, ph, gas-phase-chemistry

When water is in vapour state, to which degree is there still some dissociation with the existence of charged species like $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{HO-}$? (I would be interested by any reference to experimental studies that attempted to measure the amount of such charged species in water vapour.)

Alternatively, would you know what experimental techniques could be used to make a direct experimental measurement of the amount of charges species in a gas?

Comment: Eventual thermodynamic equilibrium is highly disturbed by ion creation due ongoing ionization by radon-222 decay and cosmic radiation.

Comment: Saying that there are no ions in gas would be a good initial approximation.